# How do I interpret pycaffe classify.py output?

Tags: neural-network, caffe, pycaffe, nvidia-digits

I created a GoogleNet Model via Nvidia DIGITS with two classes (called positive and negative).

If I classify an image with DIGITS, it shows me a nice result like positive: 85.56% and negative: 14.44%.

If it pass that model it into pycaffe's [classify.py](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/classify.py) with the same image, I get a result like `array([[ 0.38978559, -0.06033826]], dtype=float32)`

So, how do I read/interpret this result? How do I calculate the confidence levels (not sure if this is the right term) shown by DIGITS from the results shown by `classify.py`?

Comment: it seems like the `deploy.prototxt` you feed to `classify.py` is missing the last `"Softmax"` layer.

Comment: The last layer entry is ```layer {
  name: "prob"
  type: "Softmax"
  bottom: "loss3/classifier"
  top: "prob"
}
```

Comment: it is a bit odd. as usually `"Softmax"` layer should output values in range `[0..1]` that sum to one... can you look at the log and see what output layer you are actually getting?

Comment: Here is the [log output](https://gist.github.com/pogopaule/5a74d504c5d98b39c107b184f85808b3#file-classify-py-output) and the full [deploy.prototxt](https://gist.github.com/pogopaule/5a74d504c5d98b39c107b184f85808b3#file-deploy-prototxt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/2515) led me to the solution.

As the log shows, the network produces [three outputs](https://gist.github.com/pogopaule/5a74d504c5d98b39c107b184f85808b3#file-classify-py-output-L3247-L3249). `Classifier#classify` only returns the [first output](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/8714b53719165e42f7844126f671f32ecc9b2e2f/python/caffe/classifier.py#L91). So e.g. by changing `predictions = out[self.outputs[0]]` to `predictions = out[self.outputs[2]]`, I get the desired values.